# How we can monitor users activity on SharePoint online without external analytics?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, office365api, sharepoint-rest-api

How can we monitor users activity on SharePoint online pages, such as viewing viewing video or viewing PowerPoint or pdf or reading content on pages and also times that users stay in specific page?

I want to do this without any external analytics ?

Comment: Have you had any further questions about this thread?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Audit Log** to check user activities on SharePoint Online.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/compliance/search-the-audit-log-in-security-and-compliance?view=o365-worldwide

**Note**: Currently, there are no times that users stay on a specific page.

Besides, there are other usage reports, you can check if they are helpful for you.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/activity-reports/activity-reports?view=o365-worldwide